# Book about a kid in VR sci-fi

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

I read a book that was science fiction in the future (nearish). It was about a kid who played a game and his school was hosted in VR. There was this massive VR wide scavenger hunt that the winner got control of the VR company. It was a decent length book and relatively new. Any ideas on what book it was?

I think there is another company that has groups that are trying to win for the company and they kill the main-chars guardian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *Ready Player One* by Ernest Cline, published 2011. It's a perfect match for your specifications.  Set in the 2040s, the main character is Wade Watts who is one of perhaps millions of searchers for certain Easter eggs in OASIS, a virtual reality game that seems to be the main recreation of most of the people in the world. The bad guys are IOI.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a film based on this book is coming out soon.

Comment: @JustinLardinois YES!